# Uso webpack en una aplicacion basica, pero no parece que este empaquetando el codigo correctamente

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Mi problema esque quiero ejecutar esta aplicacion con webpack usando el servidor de pruebas de webpack el cual aun no consigo usar adecuadamente, siempre me da problemas, el codigo es bastante sencillo solo es una funcion flecha en javascript la cual mando a llamar despues, pero me aparece el error de que no esta declarada al ejecutar webpack en modo de desarrollo

El script es muy sencillo uso babel para traspilar a es5

```
import style from "./style.css";

const arr = [1,2,3];

codeESNext= () => {console.log(...arr)};


console.log('Hola mundo con webpack :O');

codeESNext();
```

y la configuracion en webpack es:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugion = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");


module.exports = {
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.js$/i,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader:"babel-loader",
                }
            },
            {
                test:/\.html/i,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:"html-loader",
                        options:{
                            minimize:true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/i,
                use:[
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugion({
            template:"./src/index.html",
            filename:"./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Adicionalmente los comandos que estoy usando son:

```
{
  "name": "webpackfive",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-foo": "webpack --mode development --entry ./foo/src/index.js --output-path ./foo/dist",
    "build-foo": "webpack --mode production --entry ./foo/src/index.js --output-path ./foo/dist",
    "help": "webpack -h",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"
  }
}
```

Pero al ejecutar el servidor de prueba me sale:

```
main.js:321 Uncaught ReferenceError: codeESNext is not defined
    at eval (index.js:6:12)
    at Module../src/index.js (main.js:30:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:318:33)
    at main.js:1487:37
    at main.js:1489:12
```

Lo cual no se que a que se debe, pero probablemente sea a alguna configuracion, eh buscado en la documentacion pero no veo nada que me logre solucionar el problema.

Comment: El error está en tu código, no parece tener nada que ver con `webpack`. Tienes que usar `var`, `let` o `const` para declarar la función  `codeESNext`. Por ejemplo: `const codeESNext= () => {console.log(...arr)};`

Comment: mms hombre, muchas gracias ya me funciono, xd, claro como el traspilador usa el modo estricto necesito declarar todo, jajaja espero ya no se me olvide